# No matching certficate

Tags: ios, certificate, nativescript, sidekick

When I try to build my app from Nativescript with Distribution certificate and provisioning profile, I encounter this issue :

[xcode-build] error: No certificate matching 'iPhone Distribution: xxxxxxx (xxxxxxx)' found: Select a different signing certificate for CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY, a team that matches your selected certificate, or switch to automatic provisioning. (in target 'leveldb-library')

I putted xxxxx to not reveal some informations.

My Developper account name has accent, and Nativescript doesn't want to build (in the cloud). I tried to force build.xconfig :

- CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY with accent, without accent, with ê and with specials caracters "Ãª"...
- DEVELOPMENT_TEAM with id provided by Apple developper account
- I tried to put a podfile with ios 9...
- With another apple developper account, without accent, I can build the app.
- I can build with development profiles...

I'm just stuck at this time. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `iPhone Distribution` not `Apple Distribution` which only works on Xcode 11. Can you update with content of your `build.xcconfig` file and the command you use for build.

Comment: Yes I'lm sure. I update client name without accent, and Voilà or Bingo ! I build :-)